# Select Random Values From an Array

Tags: arrays, sorting

I have an array of 5 numbers and will like to select 'ANY 3' numbers randomly
from my array to produce the result below. I've looked and can't find a code
that will reproduce the exact results. I was thinking a for loo' with a
function will be the best bet but how do I go about it, any help, (JavaScript,
Java, php) will be be appreciated please

```
var myArray = ["1","2","3","4","5"];  
var result = myArray.slice(); 

for (i=0; i < result; i++) {
  console.log(myArray[i]);
}

Results:
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 5
1 3 4
1 3 5
1 4 5
2 3 4
2 3 5
2 4 5
3 4 5
```

Comment: Get a random number in the boundarys of the array-size and use this to get the element. How to do this really depends on the language

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need something like this:  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bpg-8ix

You could put it in a function and call it in a `for` loop as many times as you want to.

Answer (score 0):

For `php` you can use `array_rand` function with the help from [HERE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

you can also use:

`shuffle($array)` then `array_rand($array,3)`

Answer (score 0):

Try My PHP sample:

```
<?php
$a=array("1","2","3","4","5");

for($i=1;$i<10;$i++){
$random_keys=array_rand($a,3);
echo $a[$random_keys[0]].$a[$random_keys[1]].$a[$random_keys[2]];
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var myArray = ["1","2","3","4","5"];  

for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * (myArray.length - 1))]);
}
```

- **Math.random()** returns a float between 0 and 1
- **myArray.length** returns array length
- **Math.floor()** rounds the result of the multiplication

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I would take to get what you want:

1. Create an array with the numbers 1 to 5.
2. Create an empty result array that will hold your resulting 3 random picks.
3. While the result array does not have a size of 3, do the following...
4. ... Pick a random number from your numbers array.
5. ... As long as that number is not already in your result array, add it to the array.
6. ... If it is already in the array, keep picking and checking until you get one that isn't in the array.

In PHP, here is how you could do the above:

```
$numbers = array(1,2,3,4,5);

// The for loop is just to show this algorithm run 10 times,
// to demonstrate the "randomness" of the result.

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  $random_three = array();
  while(sizeof($random_three) < 3) {
    $random_pick = $numbers[array_rand($numbers)];
    while (in_array($random_pick, $random_three)) {
      $random_pick = $numbers[array_rand($numbers)];
    }
    array_push($random_three, $random_pick);
  }

  print implode($random_three, " ");
  print "\n";
}
```

Output (your results **will** vary):

```
2 5 1
2 5 4
3 1 5
1 4 2
3 2 5
5 2 4
4 2 3
2 5 4
1 4 5
1 3 5
```